# How to fix flutter app stuck in loading when calling API (only Release Version)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am building an app for Covid-19.
while building the app I am calling a API via a function and want to load the content only after the API is successfully hit.

In the debug mode, everything is working fine and contents gets loaded after data is fetched from api till then it shows loading screen but in release mode, but it gets stuck in loading screen. Here is the sample code

```html
import 'package:covid_19/widgets/counter.dart';
import 'package:covid_19/widgets/my_header.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:covid_19/API/api.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart';
import 'constant.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final controller = ScrollController();
  double offset = 0;
  String countryname="All";
  bool loaded=false;
  List country=[];
  String totalcase="0";
  String infectedcase="0";
  String deathcase="0";
  String recoveredcase="0";
  String newcase="0";
  String activecase="0";
  String criticalcase="0";
  String newdeathcase="0";
  String testtotal="0";
  String day="";
  String time="";
  List stat=[];

  Future getcountry() async{
    final data=await getcountries.getdata();
    setState(() {
      country=data;
    });
    getstatss();
  }
  Future getstatss() async{
    final data=await getstats.getdata();
    setState(() {
      stat=data;
    });
    for(int i=0;i<stat.length;i++){
      if(countryname==stat[i]['country']){
        setState(() {
          totalcase=stat[i]['cases']['total'].toString();
          recoveredcase=stat[i]['cases']['recovered'].toString();
          newcase=stat[i]['cases']['new'].toString();
          activecase=stat[i]['cases']['active'].toString();
          criticalcase=stat[i]['cases']['critical'].toString();
          newdeathcase=stat[i]['deaths']['new'].toString();
          deathcase=stat[i]['deaths']['total'].toString();
          testtotal=stat[i]['tests']['total'].toString();
          day=stat[i]['day'].toString();
          time=stat[i]['time'].toString();
        });
        break;
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      loaded=true;
    });
  }


  Future filterdata() async{
    totalcase="0";
    infectedcase="0";
    deathcase="0";
    recoveredcase="0";
    newcase="0";
    activecase="0";
    criticalcase="0";
    newdeathcase="0";
    testtotal="0";
    day="";
    time="";
    setState(() {
      loaded=false;
    });
    for(int i=0;i<stat.length;i++){
      print(stat[i]);
      if(countryname==stat[i]['country']){
        print(countryname);
        totalcase=stat[i]['cases']['total'].toString();
        recoveredcase=stat[i]['cases']['recovered'].toString();
        newcase=stat[i]['cases']['new'].toString();
        activecase=stat[i]['cases']['active'].toString();
        criticalcase=stat[i]['cases']['critical'].toString();
        newdeathcase=stat[i]['deaths']['new'].toString();
        deathcase=stat[i]['deaths']['total'].toString();
        testtotal=stat[i]['tests']['total'].toString();
        day=stat[i]['day'].toString();
        time=stat[i]['time'].toString();
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      loaded=true;
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getcountry();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Covid 19",
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.blue,
          primaryColorLight: Color.fromRGBO(111, 196, 242, 1),
        ),
        darkTheme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: controller,
              child:Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  MyHeader(
                    image: "assets/icons/Drcorona.svg",
                    textTop: "You just Need",
                    textBottom: "to stay at home.",
                    offset: offset,
                  ),
                  loaded?Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    height: 60,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/maps-and-flags.svg"),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Expanded(
                          child: DropdownButton(
                            isExpanded: true,
                            underline: SizedBox(),
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/dropdown.svg"),
                            value: countryname,
                            items: country.map<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>((dynamic value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                countryname=value;
                              });
                              filterdata();

                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ):SizedBox(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  loaded?Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Case Update\n",
                                    style: kTitleTextstyle,
                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: time!=null||time==""?"Newest update ${time.split("T")[0]} ${time.split("T")[1].split("+")[0]}":"Todays Update",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: kTextLightColor,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Text(
                              "See details",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: kPrimaryColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                                blurRadius: 30,
                                color: kShadowColor,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kInfectedColor,
                                    sizeup:1.5,
                                    number: totalcase=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(totalcase),
                                    title: "Total Cases",
                                  ),

                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kInfectedColor,
                                    number: activecase=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(activecase),
                                    sizeup: 1.2,
                                    title: "Infected",
                                  ),
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kDeathColor,
                                    number: deathcase=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(deathcase),
                                    sizeup: 1.2,
                                    title: "Deaths",
                                  ),
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kRecovercolor,
                                    number: recoveredcase=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(recoveredcase),
                                    sizeup: 1.2,
                                    title: "Recovered",
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kInfectedColor,
                                    number: newcase=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(newcase),
                                    sizeup: 1,
                                    title: "New Case",
                                  ),
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kDeathColor,
                                    number: newdeathcase=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(newdeathcase),
                                    sizeup: 1,
                                    title: "New Death",
                                  ),
                                  Counter(
                                    color: kRecovercolor,
                                    number: testtotal=="null"?int.parse("0"):int.parse(testtotal),
                                    sizeup: 1,
                                    title: "Total Tests",
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Spread of Virus",
                              style: kTitleTextstyle,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "See details",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: kPrimaryColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          height: 178,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                                blurRadius: 30,
                                color: kShadowColor,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/map.png",
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ):Center(child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      Text("Connecting",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                      SizedBox(height: 50,),
                    ],

                  ),),
                ],
              )),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't any _logic_ on your `setState` methods. It should as the name suggests, mutate state only for a new state, not parse that or whatsoever. Try moving your for loop outside the `setState` and only set the `loaded = true` on it.

Comment: tried doing it, still same issue exists, I will update the edited code in the question.

Comment: You are setting your `loaded = true` in multiple places. I'd extract your parsing logic to a data model as it's making the whole widget bloated and confusing.

Comment: Is that creating the issue? I am new on it, If yes then How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure that the problem is in this block of code.
It might be a good idea to add some != null checks or at min try-catch :)

```
if(countryname==stat[i]['country']){
        print(countryname);
        totalcase=stat[i]['cases']['total'].toString();
        recoveredcase=stat[i]['cases']['recovered'].toString();
        newcase=stat[i]['cases']['new'].toString();
        activecase=stat[i]['cases']['active'].toString();
        criticalcase=stat[i]['cases']['critical'].toString();
        newdeathcase=stat[i]['deaths']['new'].toString();
        deathcase=stat[i]['deaths']['total'].toString();
        testtotal=stat[i]['tests']['total'].toString();
        day=stat[i]['day'].toString();
        time=stat[i]['time'].toString();
      }
```